# Imported DateTime but hour is not defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I am working on a basic alarm clock project for a client of mine and I've hit a wall. I have imported the datetime module but am getting a nameerror on "hour" and "sec" within my function. Any thoughts on what might be going on?

```
import tkinter
import datetime
import time
import winsound

def alarm(set_alarm_timer):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        now = current_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        date = current_time.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
        print("The Set Date is: ", date)
        print(now)
        if now == set_alarm_timer:
            print("Time to Wake up")
        winsound.PlaySound("sound.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC)
        break


def actual_time():
    set_alarm_timer = f"{hour.get()}:{min.get()}:{second.get()}"
    alarm(set_alarm_timer)

actual_time()
```

Adding the error that I get due to requests:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/will/Documents/python_projects/alarmclock.py", line 28, in
>
> actual_time()   File "/home/will/Documents/python_projects/alarmclock.py", line 25, in
> actual_time
> set_alarm_timer = f"{hour.get()}:{min.get()}:{second.get()}" NameError: name 'hour' is not defined

Comment: `date = cureent_time.strftime("%d/%m/%y")` has a typo.  Also, add the actual error you get/see for a better answer

Comment: what makes you think `hour` should be defined?

Comment: Try `set_alarm_timer = f"{datetime.datetime.now().hour}:{datetime.datetime.now().minute}:{datetime.datetime.now().second}"`.  It may be an idea to import datetime with `from datetime import datetime` and then you can swap `datetime.datetime.now()` etc. for `datetime.now()`

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this NameError because you're trying to access variables that do not exist yet (nothing has been assigned to these names).

On the first line inside `actual_time`, you use the names `hour`, `min` and `second` inside an f-string and, because of that, python tries to look up those variables and, because nothing has been assigned to them yet, it raises this error.

You don't get an error for `min`, though, because there`s already something assigned to that name, which is the [built-in function min](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min).

Answer (score 0):

I think your misunderstanding is that importing `datetime` will somehow magically create the variables `hour`, `min` and `second`. This is not the case.